# need to generate text box automatically when i'm click on the mouse point in the .net form

Tags: c#, winforms

i gust need to generate text box automatically(not manually ) when i'm click on the mouse point in the .net form. ex : if i click in mouse point in C#.net form. then i want to generate text box for particular form.

tnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this sample:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseDown);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        tb.Width = 100;
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

Comment: hii HABJAN,

its perfectly working tnxxxx for it. but.. can u tell me if i click on mouse point in that image (while after i'm browsing the image in pictureBox(i'm telling after execute the particulate form)) so then i need to generate textbox on that particulate pictureBoximage. so how can this code modify for it... plss tell me..i'm stuck with that part.

plss help me..tnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Location = new Point(75, 75);
    this.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```

Comment: @HABJAN - doh, you beat me to it :-)